# Find .closest() .next() then toggleClass

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show many different categories of things on a page for a user to choose multiples of. When a category is clicked, a checkbox is checked. Upon clicking the I'm also trying to add a class to the covering mask, but its not finding it. I'm trying to find the closest, next class `.mask`

HTML:

```
<label class="selector">
    <input name="category[]" value="53" type="checkbox">
    <div class="thumbnail choose">                          
        <div class="chooseWrap">                                
             <img src="/images/registration/cats/53.jpg" alt="Art &amp; Design">
             <div class="mask"><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i><br>Art &amp; Design</div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">Art &amp; Design</div>
    </div>                      
</label>
    <label class="selector">
    <input name="category[]" value="54" type="checkbox">
    <div class="thumbnail choose">                          
        <div class="chooseWrap">                                
             <img src="/images/registration/cats/53.jpg" alt="People">
             <div class="mask"><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i><br>People</div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">People</div>
    </div>                      
</label>
```

JQuery

```
$('.Choose').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.mask').next().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: `.closest()` selects the closest parent element. You should use `.find()` method instead, Also the selector should be `.choose` not `.Choose` and the `.mask` elements don't have _next_ siblings, so the `.next()` method doesn't return any element, this means that the whole logic _unfortunately_ is wrong.

Comment: Possible typo `class="choose"` vs capitalized `.Choose`?

Comment: Actually, what do you want to do with `next()`?. `.mask` does not have any element 'next' to him.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Good catch, it was a typo on here only, actual code is case correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looking at your `markup`, You have to use `.find()` as per your need. `.closest()` will search for the elements by travelling up the `DOM` tree.

Try,

```
$('.choose').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.mask').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly